# How to instantiate an object to a randomised Vector2

Tags: unity, 2d, android, javascript

So I'm trying to make a little game where squares randomly spawn around a set area and you have to tap them. The game is 2D. I'm having trouble using my randomly generated x and y floats to instantiate a cube in the game. Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict

public var play = false;
public var xpos : float;
public var ypos : float;
public var cube : GameObject;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
}

function Game () {
    xpos = Random.Range(-10f,10f);
    ypos = Random.Range(-4.45f,4.45f);
    Instantiate(cube, new Vector2(xpos, ypos));
}
```

And here's the error!

```
Assets/gameController.js(18,20): BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.Rigidbody, UnityEngine.Vector2)' was found.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
-Alex

Comment: `cube` should be a `GameObject` (the prefab of the thing to spawn), but a `Rigidbody`.  Also the other parameters don't match any `Object.Instantiate()` signature.

Comment: Thanks @Droppy, I'm still getting the error message though

Comment: Hold on... Thanks @Droppy, I looked up the signature and found that I was just mission Quaternion.Idenity

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of help from @Droopy I was able to figure out the solution. I was simply missing a few arguments from the Instantiate function.